# R special reshape of data tables

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data table, with a key id and a column with text value.
The key id is no unique (some lines share the same id ; there may be 1 to 8 line with a same id). I would like a data table, with unique key id and 8 columns.

For example, What I have:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
out<-data.table(id=c(rep("id1",3),rep("id2",2),"id3"),value=paste("value",round(rnorm(6,0,100))))
out
#     id     value
# 1: id1  value 49
# 2: id1  value 74
# 3: id1  value 58
# 4: id2 value -31
# 5: id2 value 151
# 6: id3  value 39
```

Desired output:

```
data.table(id=c("id1","id2","id3"),value1=c("value -63","value 160","value -82"),value2=c("value 18","value 33",NA),value3=c("value -84",NA,NA))
#    id    value1   value2    value3
#1: id1 value -63 value 18 value -84
#2: id2 value 160 value 33        NA
#3: id3 value -82       NA        NA
```

Comment: (+1) Very nice question for a newcomer. I wish all newcomers were like you...

Answer (score 4):

You could try: (`setnames` part is contributed by @David Arenburg)

```
 res <- setnames(dcast.data.table(out[, N:=1:.N,by=id], id~N, value.var="value"),
                                                     2:4, paste0("value", 1:3))
 res   
 #     id   value1    value2        value3
 # 1: id1 value -63 value 18 value -84
 # 2: id2 value 160 value 33        NA
 # 3: id3 value -82       NA        NA
```

Or a compact version suggested by @David Arenburg

```
 dcast.data.table(out[, N := paste0('value', 1:.N), by = id],
                                    id ~ N, value.var = "value")
```

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks for the edit. I guess I need to use `setnames` to get the correct names.

Comment: I don't think that matters that much, could do something like `res <- setnames(dcast.data.table(out[, N:=1:.N,by=id], id~N, value.var="value"), 2:4, paste0("value", 1:3))`

Comment: Or a more general solution, maybe `res <- setnames(dcast.data.table(out[, N:=1:.N,by=id], id~N, value.var="value"), seq_along(unique(out$id)) + 1, paste0("value", seq_along(unique(out$id))))`

Comment: The first version is less general. The second one the way to go I think

Comment: I think you can do it in one go `dcast.data.table(out[, N := paste0('value', 1:.N), by = id], id ~ N, value.var = "value")`

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks, that is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(value~id,data=out,FUN=paste,collapse=" ")

id                        value
1 id1 value -63 value 18 value -84
2 id2           value 160 value 33
3 id3                    value -82
```

It's not identical to your desired output, but it does the trick anyway.

Comment: Note that you can change the separator by adding a character in `collapse` parameter.

Comment: Did you notice it is a `data.table` question by any chance? Why would he use `aggregate`? He can do the same with `data.table` such as `out[, paste(value, collapse = " "), by = id]`, but doesn't reach his desired ouput either way

Answer (score 0):

Only using R base functions can be accomplish the task as below:

```
out$ID <- unlist(lapply(as.vector(table(out$id)), function(x) 1:x))
reshape(out, idvar="id", timevar="ID", direction="wide")
```

**Output**

```
    id   value.1  value.2   value.3
1: id1 value -63 value 18 value -84
2: id2 value 160 value 33      <NA>
3: id3 value -82     <NA>      <NA>
```